# Noob trying to code a twitterbot trying to scrape accounts. Error filtering data for accounts in twitter ""statuses" not recognized" in py

Tags: python, twitter, bots

I am new to programming please, help.

I am trying to build a bot that scrapes twitter accounts that are based in the US with followers between 10k and 50k and then exports it to an excel file.

I got the code from chatgpt and adjusted it to my specifications **the errors seems to be a problem with the formating of the Twitter API, since it doesn't recognize statuses**. But it could be something else. I do not understand what I could do to fix this.

I'll add the code here:

```
import requests
import json
import xlwt

# Set Twitter API credentials
api_key = "xxx"
api_secret_key = "xxx"
access_token = "xxx"
access_token_secret = "xxx"

# Set query and number of tweets to retrieve
query = "from:twitter user:twitter lang:en"
count = 100

# Set OAuth 1.0a headers for the request
headers = {
    "Authorization": "OAuth oauth_consumer_key={api_key}, oauth_nonce={nonce}, oauth_signature={signature}, oauth_signature_method={signature_method}, oauth_timestamp={timestamp}, oauth_token={access_token}, oauth_version={version}".format(
        api_key=api_key,
        nonce="random_string",
        signature="signed_string",
        signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
        timestamp="current_timestamp",
        access_token=access_token,
        version="1.0"
    ),
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

# Execute GET request to the Twitter API
response = requests.get(
    "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q={query}&count={count}".format(
        query=query,
        count=count
    ),
    headers=headers
)

# Extract JSON data from the response
data = json.loads(response.text)

# Filter the data for accounts with 10,000 to 50,000 followers located in the USA
filtered_data = [user for user in data["statuses"] if user["user"]["location"] == "USA" and 10000 <= user["user"]["followers_count"] <= 50000]

# Extract the account name for each account
account_data = []
for user in filtered_data:
    account_name = user["user"]["screen_name"]
    account_data.append({"Account Name": account_name})

# Export the account data to an Excel file
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

# Write header row
header_row = ["Account Name"]
for col_num, header in enumerate(header_row):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, header)

# Write data rows
for row_num, account in enumerate(account_data):
    worksheet.write(row_num + 1, 0, account["Account Name"])

# Save the workbook
workbook.save("twitter_accounts.xls")
```

I really do not know what I should do to fix the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\A\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\230224_twitterbot.py", line 42, in <module>
    filtered_data = [user for user in data["statuses"] if user["user"]["location"] == "USA" and 10000 <= user["user"]["followers_count"] <= 50000]
                                      ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'statuses'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am expecting the code to work. :)

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that you never tried to `print(data)'` to make sure that you're actually getting the correct response.  Pretty good chance your api call is failing and you don't know it

Comment: probably your dict `data` doesn't have the key `statuses` 
try to print the `data` before this line and see if it  does have it.

Comment: I get this when I print(data): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\A\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\230224_twitterbot.py", line 44, in <module>
    filtered_data = [user for user in data["statuses"] if user["user"]["location"] == "USA" and 10000 <= user["user"]["followers_count"] <= 50000]
                                      ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'statuses'
{'errors': [{'code': 215, 'message': 'Bad Authentication data.'}]}

Process finished with exit code 1